# Spring Security: Obtaining OAuth Token from a Java application

Tags: spring, url, oauth

I have an API with a set of REST Services inside an app that is securized with Spring Security. The services work fine, but now I need to develop a little JAVA client that consumes this REST Services.

This services are securized with an OAuth Token and I´m trying to find the way to obtain this Token.

```
URL myURL = new URL("http://localhost:8080/oauth/token");
String userPassword = "user:user";
String encoding = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(userPassword.getBytes());
URLConnection uc = myURL.openConnection();
uc.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
```

Now, I have something like this, but It doesn´t work fine and I can´t obtain the Token that I need to invoke the services.

Could anyone help me?

Regards!.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have found the workaround:

```
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.DefaultOAuth2ClientContext;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.DefaultAccessTokenRequest;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.password.ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.password.ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken;

private static String baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080";
private static String tokenUrl = "http://localhost:8080/oauth/token";

ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider provider = new ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider();
ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails resource = new ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails();
//resource.setClientAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.none);
resource.setAccessTokenUri(tokenUrl);
resource.setScope(Arrays.asList("yourScope"));
resource.setClientId("yourClientId");
resource.setClientSecret("yourClientSecret");
resource.setGrantType("password");
resource.setUsername("yourUser");
resource.setPassword("yourPass");
OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = provider.obtainAccessToken(resource, new DefaultAccessTokenRequest());
OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(resource, new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext(accessToken));
String result = restTemplate.getForObject(baseUrl+"/myExample", String.class);
System.err.println(result);
```

And in my pom.xml the content is:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring dependences -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0.pr2</version>
    </dependency>
```

This example works fine